# Extract string after the last slash in perl

Tags: perl

i am using perl regular expression to match everything after the last slash. after reading the perl doc, i realised that following can be the code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $a = "E:/one/two/abc.dll";
if ($a =~ m/([^/]+$)/)
{
 print " the value is: $a  \n";
}
```

but i am getting last string as : abc.dll. what could be the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: You turn on `use strict; use warnings;`. Did you actually try running the code after doing that, or did you just add it to appease Stack Overflow? Because it _tells you_ what's wrong if you compile this snippet: `Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/([ <-- HERE ^/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will give syntax error Because of the unescaped  `/`. First you should escape the `\/` or use other [delimiters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Then in your print statement you are printing the `$a` so you will get the full  data.

You should use `$&` to print the matched pattern or `$1` to print the first grouped element.

In my below code I used `$1`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $data = "E:/one/two/abc.dll";

if ($data =~ m/([^\/]+)$/)  
{
   print " the value is: $1  \n";
}
```

And then please avoid using `$a` and `$b` as a variable name this won't give the syntax error or warning. But these are reserved keywords for sort.

Comment: ... and you shouldn't use `$a`, ever, because it has a special meaning in `perl` and even if it didn't, single letter variable names are filthy. More importantly - the `use strict; use warnings;` that the OP included in their code would prevent it from compiling and tell them _exactly_ what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good job for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). The below example splits the line on a slash character into a list, then simply extracts the last entry (in this case, `abc.dll`):

```
my $file = (split '/', $data)[-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing you have looks like a path. If that's true, you'd be better off using a module that's designed to parse paths in a portable way.

All examples below assume use of `strict` and `warnings`.

[File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec)

```
use File::Spec;
my ($volume, $dirs, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath('E:/one/two/abc.dll');
```

[File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename)

```
use File::Basename;
my ($file, $dirs) = fileparse('E:/one/two/abc.dll');
```

[Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use Path::Tiny;
my $path = path('E:/one/two/abc.dll');
my $file = $path->basename;
my $dirs = $path->parent->stringify;
```

Comment: this is the better answer